# How to manage collection of Bitmap for longer time?

Tags: .net, bitmap, garbage-collection, c++-cli

In Winforms project, I have a collection of Bitmap (`List` of `Bitmap`) and I am adding `Bitmap` files into this collection.
 At some point of time this `List` gets automatically reduced by `GC`, this way I am loosing data whenever Garbage Collector runs. 

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074434/is-it-possible-to-stop-net-garbage-collection) post and included the Global `List` variable into  `GC.AddMemoryPressure` but still GC is removing most of the data from `List` variable.
How to make sure that my big `List` of `Bitmap` stays unchanged on memory for longer duration?

Comment: GC should not affect a `List` nor its contents as long as you have a live reference on it. However, if you loaded the bitmaps from a file or Stream, you may have a problem from their own lifetime management.

Comment: i'm loading Bitmap from camera input, at no particular time, when `GC` runs i see that memory consumption gets reduced by almost half (if 2gb ram is used, after `GC` runs then it comes down to 1gb)

Comment: That's because non-contiguous data is moved around, eliminating gaps, and that way memory pages can be freed. You're not losing data (but if you have unmanaged pointers to your bitmaps' data, these pointers can be left dangling).